# Rewrite Host name based on request header in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, url-routing, azure-application-gateway

I am aware that we can use **rewrites** in azure application gateway to rewrite your url, request/response headers.
But How can we modify our host based on a condition.

I have already tried rewriting **Header Host** but Appgw gives me error: that you can't do it as you have backend action associated with this

Answer (score 0):

> I have already tried rewriting **Header Host** but Appgw gives me error: that you can't do it as you have backend action associated with this.

***Note*** that Azure Application gateway rewrite rule as limitation -   Rewrites aren't supported when the application gateway is configured to redirect the requests or to show a custom error page. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#limitations).

If you have a backend action associated with the Host header, you can try using the rewrite rule to modify the Location header instead. You can set the host name in the Location header to the application gateway.

In Application gateway, create rewrite rule set and add if condition with regular expression pattern    as per your requirement I have added variable with header and pattern to match like below `(https?):\/\/.*azurewebsites.net(.*)$`

[image]

Then in action type select `set` for action type and `respose` in response type

[image]

This value will replace `azurewebsites.net` with `google.com` in the location header.

[image]

***Reference***:

[Rewrite HTTP headers and URL with Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#limitations)

Comment: this will not change my host correct. I want to redirect my request to different host as per condition specified.
Note: I am using haproxy as ingress controller and thats why my aks cluster is already used as overrided host in backend settings

Comment: if you are using HAProxy as an ingress controller and your AKS cluster is already used as an overridden host in the backend settings, you may need to modify the backend settings in HAProxy to redirect the request to the desired host based on the condition specified.